# easymock test no method execution

Tags: junit, easymock

I've got such block in my method

```
@Override
protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
    if (null != processor) {
        processor.process();
    } else {
        LOGGER.warn("Job was not initialized correctly.");
    }
}
```

To cover `processor.process()` I wrote this test

```
@Test
public void testExecuteInternal() throws JobExecutionException {
    JobExecutionContext context = createMock(JobExecutionContext.class);
    processor.process();
    expectLastCall();
    replay(processor);

    job.executeInternal(context);
    verify(processor);
}
```

But how to cover block where `process` is not executed?

Comment: How is your code block getting the `processor` instance?

Comment: I create mock object `processor = createMock(Processor.class);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a setter method to set the `processor` for `executeInternal`, to test the block where `process` is not executed, in your test case, use the setter to set `processor` to `null`.

So instead of `processor = EasyMock.createMock(Processor.class)`

You will have for this test `processor = null`

That should do the trick.

Comment: won't it throw null pointer exception when I attempt to call `processor.process`?

Comment: No. Because `if(null != processor)` will be false.

Comment: I mean in my test method

Comment: You will have to write a separate test to test the flow where process is not executed. In this new test, since `processor` is null and hence won't be used in `executeInternal` you don't need to define any behavior. Hence I don't see any reason why it will throw an NPE.

Comment: Then I don't understand. What does test method should contain? I mean what will be the difference between the current method and new one?

Comment: You need two tests. First one to check the flow when `process` is executed. This is the test that you have in your post and that will correctly cover this flow. Now you need to write a second test to check the flow when `process` is NOT executed. In this test you need to set `processor` to null to cover the flow where `process` is not executed.